# AWS boto3 User: arn:aws:iam::xxxx:root is not authorized to perform: lambda:AddLayerVersionPermission on resource

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3

```
import json
import boto3
client = boto3.client('lambda')
response = client.add_layer_version_permission(
    LayerName='arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:xxxx:layer:AWSLambda-Python38-SciPy1x',
    VersionNumber=29,
    StatementId='xaccount',
    Action='lambda:GetLayerVersion',
    Principal='*',
)
print(response)
```

setp1) setup aws credentials

step2) Created new IAM admin user and assigned policies to that user **AdministratorAccess,AWSLambda_FullAccess, AWSLambdaExecute**

step3) after running the python script I am getting error

```
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (AccessDeniedException) when calling the AddLayerVersionPermission operation: User: arn:aws:iam::xxxx:root is not authorized to perform: lambda:AddLayerVersionPermission on resource: arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:xxxx:layer:AWSLambda-Python38-SciPy1x:29
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The layer you are trying to modify:

```
arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:xxxx:layer:AWSLambda-Python38-SciPy1
```

is [AWS managed public layer](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-for-aws-lambda-use-any-programming-language-and-share-common-components/). It does not belong to you, thus you **can't modify its permissions**, explaining why you are denied doing this.